# How to do Low Level Format (Hard Format) for a Laptop HardDrive

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

I have 2 questions

1. Can we know weather a Hard Drive has
   done Low Level format or not.
   Somehow using a tool ?
2. How to do Low Level Format (Hard Format) for a        Laptop HardDrive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do a 'proper' oldschool low level format with modern drives - they require specialised software, and it only really needs to be done once, at the place its made.

You can however wipe the drive with [dban](http://www.dban.org/) - with modern drives a single pass is often enough, DOD recommends 7 passes, and the guttmann method basically runs every possible wiping algorithm for pretty much every sort of drive ever made.

Depends on how much time you're willing to spend.

[more info here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Recovering_Overwritten_Data) if you are into the science of it.

Answer (score 0):

With Low-Level you mean to overwrite the drive with zeros or random data?

For Question 2: You can do this with every Linux Live CD and the dd command. Something like

> $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX

should do the trick. Alternatively you can use a specialised distribution like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org).

Comment: If xe means that, xe has the wrong idea of what a low-level format actually _is_. ☺

Answer (score 0):

You can check content of the hard drive with `hexdump`. Actual destroying data with `dd` mentioned above or with `shred`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data security, buy an industrial shredder.  All sorts of interesting forensic techniques can be applied to hard drives of all types to retrieve data you "thought" was gone.